# convert string PTIM into ISO 8601 PT1M in java

Tags: java, jodatime, iso8601

How to convert the String data type as PT1M to ISO 8601 Time Standard in Java?

eg: `String date=" PT1M ";` convert into ISO 861 time standard.

Answer (score 1):

“PT1M” is a period of time (“one minute”), not a time in itself.  It is already in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.  As such I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but I think that you want:

```
final Period period = new Period("PT1M");
```

Comment: PT1M stands for a duration of 1 minute as per your link.